# Search and replace from other sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm stucked on a code problem, anther user helped me with this, what the code is suppoused to do is search in a sheet for last information, and then replace next blank cells for the information from other sheet. The code was working and i didnt move it at all, then when i finished the proyect i try it out and the code didnt work. R2 is not detecting the last blank cell well, instead when the range has information it repleaces the first non blank cell, when it doesnt have information it goes 5 rows below.

Image 1 This is the format which people Will fill, the example searches for 346

Image 2 Then the 346 format where it should paste the info is like this (It already has info)

Image 3 Adding the info should end up like this (adding the info below the old info instead of rewriting it)

[image]

```
Private Sub C1_Click()

Dim Partida As String
Dim Rng As Range, r1 As Range, r2 As Range, UPa As Range
Dim Respuesta As String

If Sheets("Materiales").Range("C4").Value <> "Blanco" Then

'------------------------> Color
Sheets("Color").Unprotect
    Partida = Worksheets("Materiales").Range("C3").Value

        If Trim(Partida) <> "" Then
            With Sheets("Color").Rows("6:6")
                Set Rng = .Find(What:=Partida, After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
                If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                    Set r2 = Rng.Offset(4, -1).End(xlDown)
                    'If r2.Row > 19 Then
                     '   Set r2 = Rng.Offset(4, -1)
                    'Else
                        'Set r2 = r2.Offset(1)
                    'End If
                    For Each r1 In Worksheets("Materiales").Range("B7:B16")
                        If Len(r1) > 0 Then
                            r2.Resize(, 2).Value = r1.Resize(, 2).Value
                            Set r2 = r2.Offset(1)
                        End If
                    Next r1
```

The complete code:

```
Private Sub C1_Click()

Dim Partida As String
Dim Rng As Range, r1 As Range, r2 As Range, UPa As Range
Dim Respuesta As String

If Sheets("Materiales").Range("C4").Value <> "Blanco" Then

'------------------------> Color
Sheets("Color").Unprotect
    Partida = Worksheets("Materiales").Range("C3").Value

        If Trim(Partida) <> "" Then
            With Sheets("Color").Rows("6:6")
                Set Rng = .Find(What:=Partida, After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
                If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                    Set r2 = Rng.Offset(4, -1).End(xlDown)
                    'If r2.Row > 19 Then
                     '   Set r2 = Rng.Offset(4, -1)
                    'Else
                        'Set r2 = r2.Offset(1)
                    'End If
                    For Each r1 In Worksheets("Materiales").Range("B7:B16")
                        If Len(r1) > 0 Then
                            r2.Resize(, 2).Value = r1.Resize(, 2).Value
                            Set r2 = r2.Offset(1)
                        End If
                    Next r1
                Finalizar = MsgBox("Información Agregada", vbOKOnly)
                Sheets("Materiales").Range("C2:C4").Value = ""
                Sheets("Materiales").Range("B7:C16").Value = ""


                Else
                    Respuesta = MsgBox("No se encontró, desea agregar la partida: " & Worksheets("Materiales").Range("C3").Value, vbYesNo, "Partida no encontrada")
                    If Respuesta = vbYes Then
                        With Sheets("Color").Rows("5:5")
                            Set UPa = .Find(What:="", Lookat:=xlWhole)
                            UPaD = UPa.Column
                        End With

                        Sheets("Patrón").Range("A1:C39").Copy
                        With Sheets("Color")
                            .Cells(5, UPaD).PasteSpecial PASTE:=xlPasteColumnWidths
                            .Cells(5, UPaD).PasteSpecial PASTE:=xlPasteAll
                        End With

                        With Sheets("Color")
                            Llenado = UPaD + 1
                            .Cells(5, Llenado).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("C2").Value
                            .Cells(6, Llenado).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("C3").Value
                            .Cells(7, Llenado).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("C4").Value
                            .Cells(10, UPaD).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("B7").Value
                            .Cells(10, Llenado).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("C7").Value
                            .Cells(11, UPaD).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("B8").Value
                            .Cells(11, Llenado).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("C8").Value
                            .Cells(12, UPaD).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("B9").Value
                            .Cells(12, Llenado).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("C9").Value
                            .Cells(13, UPaD).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("B10").Value
                            .Cells(13, Llenado).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("C10").Value
                            .Cells(14, UPaD).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("B11").Value
                            .Cells(14, Llenado).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("C11").Value
                            .Cells(15, UPaD).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("B12").Value
                            .Cells(15, Llenado).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("C12").Value
                            .Cells(16, UPaD).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("B13").Value
                            .Cells(16, Llenado).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("C13").Value
                            .Cells(17, UPaD).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("B14").Value
                            .Cells(17, Llenado).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("C14").Value
                            .Cells(18, UPaD).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("B15").Value
                            .Cells(18, Llenado).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("C15").Value
                            .Cells(19, UPaD).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("B16").Value
                            .Cells(19, Llenado).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("C16").Value
                        End With
                        Finalizar = MsgBox("Información Agregada", vbOKOnly)
                        Sheets("Materiales").Range("C2:C4").Value = ""
                        Sheets("Materiales").Range("B7:C16").Value = ""
                        End If


                    If Respuesta = vbNo Then
                        Sheets("Materiales").Activate
                    End If


                End If
            End With
            Sheets("Color").Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
        Else
        PartidaN = MsgBox("Agregar partida", vbCritical, "Error")

        End If
Else

'--------------------------> Blanco
Sheets("Blanco").Unprotect
Partida = Worksheets("Materiales").Range("C3").Value

        If Trim(Partida) <> "" Then
            With Sheets("Blanco").Rows("6:6")
                Set Rng = .Find(What:=Partida, After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
                If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                    Set r2 = Rng.Offset(4, -1).End(xlDown)
                    If r2.Row > 19 Then
                        Set r2 = Rng.Offset(4, -1)
                    Else
                        Set r2 = r2.Offset(1)
                    End If
                    For Each r1 In Worksheets("Materiales").Range("B7:B16")
                        If Len(r1) > 0 Then
                            r2.Resize(, 2).Value = r1.Resize(, 2).Value
                            Set r2 = r2.Offset(1)
                        End If
                    Next r1
                Finalizar = MsgBox("Información Agregada", vbOKOnly)
                Sheets("Materiales").Range("C2:C4").Value = ""
                Sheets("Materiales").Range("B7:C16").Value = ""
                Else
                    Respuesta = MsgBox("No se encontró, desea agregar la partida: " & Worksheets("Materiales").Range("C3").Value, vbYesNo, "Partida no encontrada")
                    If Respuesta = vbYes Then
                        With Sheets("Blanco").Rows("5:5")
                            Set UPa = .Find(What:="", Lookat:=xlWhole)
                            UPaD = UPa.Column
                        End With

                        Sheets("Patrón").Range("A1:C39").Copy
                        With Sheets("Blanco")
                            .Cells(5, UPaD).PasteSpecial PASTE:=xlPasteColumnWidths
                            .Cells(5, UPaD).PasteSpecial PASTE:=xlPasteAll
                        End With

                        With Sheets("Blanco")
                            Llenado = UPaD + 1
                            .Cells(5, Llenado).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("C2").Value
                            .Cells(6, Llenado).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("C3").Value
                            .Cells(7, Llenado).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("C4").Value
                            .Cells(10, UPaD).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("B7").Value
                            .Cells(10, Llenado).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("C7").Value
                            .Cells(11, UPaD).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("B8").Value
                            .Cells(11, Llenado).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("C8").Value
                            .Cells(12, UPaD).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("B9").Value
                            .Cells(12, Llenado).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("C9").Value
                            .Cells(13, UPaD).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("B10").Value
                            .Cells(13, Llenado).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("C10").Value
                            .Cells(14, UPaD).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("B11").Value
                            .Cells(14, Llenado).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("C11").Value
                            .Cells(15, UPaD).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("B12").Value
                            .Cells(15, Llenado).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("C12").Value
                            .Cells(16, UPaD).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("B13").Value
                            .Cells(16, Llenado).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("C13").Value
                            .Cells(17, UPaD).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("B14").Value
                            .Cells(17, Llenado).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("C14").Value
                            .Cells(18, UPaD).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("B15").Value
                            .Cells(18, Llenado).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("C15").Value
                            .Cells(19, UPaD).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("B16").Value
                            .Cells(19, Llenado).Value = Sheets("Materiales").Range("C16").Value
                        End With
                        Finalizar = MsgBox("Información Agregada", vbOKOnly)
                        Sheets("Materiales").Range("C2:C4").Value = ""
                        Sheets("Materiales").Range("B7:C16").Value = ""
                    End If


                    If Respuesta = vbNo Then
                        Sheets("Materiales").Activate
                    End If


                End If
            End With
            Sheets("Blanco").Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
        Else
        PartidaN = MsgBox("Agregar partida", vbCritical, "Error")

        End If

End If
End Sub
```

No error Msgs tho

Comment: Would you please elaborate more on your data, and possibly add some example data?  Please [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56954930/edit) to include that info.  Additionally, please elaborate on "didn't work very well"; you state that "the cells have information it replaces the first one" which means that the cell based on `r2`?  Need more specific language rather than the vague "cells".

Comment: I edited it, i hope it gets more understandable.

Comment: Will there ever be a case where you run out of rows to put the new data?  For example, you would need to put new data in row 20, but that's where your `Total` row is.

Comment: No, never, it will always be less. It has more rows just for esthetics.

Comment: Currently, it looks like the code prevents putting new data past row 19 by overwriting old data starting back at row 10.  You can get around this limitation by putting all of your data evaluation (total, pacas, kilos, etc) at the top of the sheet instead of underneath the data.  That way you can have signifcantly more room to grow the data without ever having to move the aggregates.  And it looks like you can just update your template sheet (`Patrón`) to put that up top.  This moves your other row references down 10, so the search happens on row 16 instead of 6 for example.

Comment: I cant move that data because its a format that my boss gave me. I dont know how to avoid overwtiting, instead i would like for the code to start pasting the info below last non blank cell. I dont quite understand how my template affect this code.

Comment: If you are unable to move your data, as @tigeravatar has suggested, then you may want to take advantage of the formatting of your cells.  You find the Partida number then move 3 rows down (you move 4 down), where you have your headers.  This will let you know if there is any data below the header, such that `If cells(9,2).font.bold = true then // lastrow = 10 //  Else  lastrow = cells(9,2).end(xldown.row+1`.  This assumes you always have headers on row 9, but could use offsets where needed; the use of a bold total value is why the check is for bold.

Answer (score 0):

Moving comment to answer, as looking at code in comments is aweful.

---

```
Set Rng = .Find(What:=Partida, After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
Set MatHead = Rng.Offset(3,-1)
If MatHead.end(xldown).font.bold = true then
    lr = MatHead.Offset(1).Row + 1
Else
    lr = MatHead.End(xlDown).Row + 1
End if
Cells(lr,1).Value = MATERIALES 'fix
Cells(lr,2).Value = KILOS 'fix
```

---

The big issue here is, if you've filled values into rows 10 through 19, you will have `.end(xldown)` always end up on row 20, which is the bolded value "Total", meaning that you will begin overwriting the row 10 value (numbering of rows based on your images).

You may want to think about avoiding that, if it is a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to be a simple row @Cyrill made me realize that, since the code cannot detect the headers, only by swapping the start range from 4 to 3 it starts detecting the headers and the information below. Thank all of you for healping me :)

```
Private Sub C1_Click()

Dim Partida As String
Dim Rng As Range, r1 As Range, r2 As Range, UPa As Range
Dim Respuesta As String

If Sheets("Materiales").Range("C4").Value <> "Blanco" Then

'------------------------> Color
Sheets("Color").Unprotect
    Partida = Worksheets("Materiales").Range("C3").Value

        If Trim(Partida) <> "" Then
            With Sheets("Color").Rows("6:6")
                Set Rng = .Find(What:=Partida, After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
                If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                    Set r2 = Rng.Offset(3, -1).End(xlDown)

                    If r2.Row > 19 Then
                        Set r2 = Rng.Offset(4, -1)
                    Else
                        Set r2 = r2.Offset(1)
                    End If
                    For Each r1 In Worksheets("Materiales").Range("B7:B16")
                        If Len(r1) > 0 Then
                            r2.Resize(, 2).Value = r1.Resize(, 2).Value
                            Set r2 = r2.Offset(1)
                        End If
                    Next r1
```